# Integrating an array of values with infinite upper limit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, numerical-integration

I am working on a chemical kinetic program that requires integrating a function from 0 to infinity. The variables in question are arrays acquired from databases. A simplified version of the variables are x, F(x), and G(x) where F(x) and G(x) are interpolated from said databases.

So I have my three arrays that I can pass in the integrand function (I am excluding the file parsing functions for reading and interpolating for F and G)-

```
def integrand(x,Y,Z):
   return x*Y*Z 
#integrate (x*F*G)dx 0 to infinity
integrated=scipy.integrate.quad(integrand,0,np.inf,args=(F,G))
```

I know this will return an error because F and G are arrays. Is there a better integration approach for an integrand that has 3 variables but are being integrated with respect to a single argument (dx in this case)?
Note: In some cases, G converges fast enough to be estimated as a float.

**Attempted solutions**

Use np.trapz with an arbitrarily large upper limit for the x array to stand in for infinity

```
x_n=np.linspace(0,10000,500)
#now, F(x_n) and G(x_n) from np.interp
vars=integrand(x_n,F,G)
answer=np.trapz(vars,x_n,dx=.01)
```

This approach may not work for other data sets and is not completely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can just use this function for each element of vector. Or if dependence from Y and Z this simple just pull this multipliers out of integral so you integrate only once and then multiply this result to `Y * Z`.

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

def integrand(x,Y,Z):
    return (1 / x ** 2) * Y * Z


Y, Z = [1, 2], [3, 4]
integrated = [integrate.quad(integrand,1,np.inf,args=(y,z)) for y, z in zip(Y, Z)]
print(integrated)
# [(3.0, 3.3306690738754696e-14), (8.0, 8.881784197001252e-14)]
```

Comment: What are the differences between the first tuple and second in the returned list? If I have len(Y)=len(Z)=100, the function returns an equal length list filled with the tuples. Would the result of the integral be the sum of integrated[:,0] ?

Comment: Also, the lower bound of the integral, a, largely affects the sum (by an order of magnitude). I will keep looking into the approach you proposed.